# Add multiple entries of text to specific lines of code in Python

Tags: python

I would like to add the flag 
`-c 4` 
to my line of code at 
`hostname = "216.58.223.3 -c 4"`

The way it currently works:

```
@staticmethod
def valve_southafrica_two():

    print("Pinging Valve South Africa 2")
    hostname = "155.133.238.163"
    response = os.system("ping " + hostname)
    if response == 0:
        pingstatus = "Active"
    else:
        pingstatus = "Error"

    print("Ping Test Complete")

    return pingstatus
```

and the way I want it to work is so:

```
@staticmethod
def valve_southafrica_two():

    print("Pinging Valve South Africa 2")
    hostname = "155.133.238.163 -c 4"
    response = os.system("ping " + hostname)
    if response == 0:
        pingstatus = "Active"
    else:
        pingstatus = "Error"

    print("Ping Test Complete")

    return pingstatus
```

for Linux +/ MacOS Pinging, is there any way to bulk add the `-c 4` flag next to the xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (IP) or is the only solution to manually add the `-c 4` next to each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [subprocess,call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)

By which we can send the commands as a list of arguments so we just need to specify `-c 4` as an argument

```
import subprocess
#import os
def valve_southafrica_two():

    print("Pinging Valve South Africa 2")
    hostname = "155.133.238.163"
    response =subprocess.call(["ping",hostname,"-c 4"])

    if response == 0:
        pingstatus = "Active"
    else:
        pingstatus = "Error"

    print("Ping Test Complete")

    return pingstatus
valve_southafrica_two()
```

OUTPUT

```
Pinging Valve South Africa 2
PING 155.133.238.163 (155.133.238.163) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 155.133.238.163: icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=327 ms
64 bytes from 155.133.238.163: icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=325 ms
64 bytes from 155.133.238.163: icmp_seq=3 ttl=47 time=326 ms
64 bytes from 155.133.238.163: icmp_seq=4 ttl=47 time=325 ms

--- 155.133.238.163 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 325.113/326.192/327.601/0.992 ms
Ping Test Complete
```

Comment: I tried it like that, didn't seem to work, I'll have to take a deeper look and see why its returning an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string formatting or f-strings like below

```
flag = '-c 4'
# python 3.6
hostname = f'155.133.238.163 {flag}'

# python 2.7
hostname = '155.133.238.163 {0}'.format(flag)
```

**Output**

`155.133.238.163 -c 4`

Comment: Will test this when I get a chance, I think I might have to just use the initial process I worked with, as it just works for MacOS, I am considering moving this service to the cloud instead of a local application, making it more simple to work with, less code and such for me to have to maintain.